# log4j stackoverflow

Tags: java, log4j, stack-overflow

This is a real stackoverflow exception on the stackoverflow site! I just wondered if anyone had seen it before - and what they used to address it.

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.lang.Exception.<init>(Exception.java:41)
at java.io.IOException.<init>(IOException.java:41)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:260)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:202)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:263)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:106)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:116)
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:203)
at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:140)
at org.apache.log4j.helpers.CountingQuietWriter.write(CountingQuietWriter.java:44)
at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.subAppend(WriterAppender.java:301)
at org.apache.log4j.contribs.DailyRollingFileAppender.subAppend(DailyRollingFileAppender.java:395)
at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.append(WriterAppender.java:159)
at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:230)
at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:65)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:203)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:388)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:835)
at org.apache.log4j.contribs.LoggingOutputStream.flush(LoggingOutputStream.java:168)
at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:432)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:202)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:272)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:85)
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flushBuffer(OutputStreamWriter.java:168)
at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:477)
at java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:619)
at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:756)
at org.apache.log4j.helpers.LogLog.error(LogLog.java:142)
at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OnlyOnceErrorHandler.error(OnlyOnceErrorHandler.java:77)
at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OnlyOnceErrorHandler.error(OnlyOnceErrorHandler.java:67)
at org.apache.log4j.helpers.CountingQuietWriter.write(CountingQuietWriter.java:48)
at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.subAppend(WriterAppender.java:301)
at org.apache.log4j.contribs.DailyRollingFileAppender.subAppend(DailyRollingFileAppender.java:395)
at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.append(WriterAppender.java:159)
at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:230)
at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:65)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:203)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:388)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:835)
at org.apache.log4j.contribs.LoggingOutputStream.flush(LoggingOutputStream.java:168)
at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:432)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:202)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:272)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:85)
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flushBuffer(OutputStreamWriter.java:168)
at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:477)
at java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:619)
at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:756)
at org.apache.log4j.helpers.LogLog.error(LogLog.java:142)
at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OnlyOnceErrorHandler.error(OnlyOnceErrorHandler.java:77)
at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OnlyOnceErrorHandler.error(OnlyOnceErrorHandler.java:67)
at org.apache.log4j.helpers.CountingQuietWriter.write(CountingQuietWriter.java:48)
at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.subAppend(WriterAppender.java:301)
at org.apache.log4j.contribs.DailyRollingFileAppender.subAppend(DailyRollingFileAppender.java:395)
at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.append(WriterAppender.java:159)
at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:230)
at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:65)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:203)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:388)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:835)
at org.apache.log4j.contribs.LoggingOutputStream.flush(LoggingOutputStream.java:168)
at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:432)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:202)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:272)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:85)
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flushBuffer(OutputStreamWriter.java:168)
at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:477)
```

... (repeated about 10 times)

```
    at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:432)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:202)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:272)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:85)
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flushBuffer(OutputStreamWriter.java:168)
at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:477)
at java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:619)
at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:756)
at org.apache.log4j.helpers.LogLog.error(LogLog.java:142)
at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OnlyOnceErrorHandler.error(OnlyOnceErrorHandler.java:77)
at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OnlyOnceErrorHandler.error(OnlyOnceErrorHandler.java:67)
at org.apache.log4j.helpers.CountingQuietWriter.write(CountingQuietWriter.java:48)
at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.subAppend(WriterAppender.java:301)
at org.apache.log4j.contribs.DailyRollingFileAppender.subAppend(DailyRollingFileAppender.java:395)
at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.append(WriterAppender.java:159)
at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:230)
at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:65)
```

java.lang.StackOverflowError

Comment: What kind of log4j configuration are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Missing your log4j configuration files and code here.

But the initial guess is that

1) [LoggingOutputStream](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/logging/log4j/trunk/contribs/JimMoore/LoggingOutputStream.java) is used somewhere in code, replacing `System.err` like this:

```
System.setErr(new PrintStream(new LoggingOutputStream(Category.getRoot(), Priority.WARN), true));
```

2) log4j is not configured properly and tries to print internal error to `System.err` in [LogLog](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/org/apache/log4j/helpers/LogLog.java#142).

This creates circular logging calls which lead to stack overflow.

Try removing `System.err` interceptor from 1). This would allow the internal error from 2) to be surfaced.

Comment: Thanx a lot. You solved our problem :-)